# Is there a way to get infinite gold in Majesty 2: Monster Kingdom?

Tags: cheats, majesty-2

When playing Majesty 2 on Steam, I can edit lib files to make extort (Rogue ability) cost -2000 gold, effectively giving me 2000 gold whenever I use the ability.

However, in Monster Kingdom, I couldn't figure out what (if any) lib files to edit.

Is there any way to cheat and/or get infinite gold on Majesty 2: Monster Kingdom?

Answer (score 2):

No infinite gold but...

According to [this Majesty 2 thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/25980/discussions/0/864951657803638864/#c828925849497934772) in Steam, you can gain gold each time you cast a Kingdom spell (i.e. *Magic Lighting* or *Healing* spells).

You just have to open `resource.pak` file as it was a rar file, extract `spells.xml` into `/resource.mod/gameData/magic` (create `/magic` folder if needed). Then modify via *Notepad*. As simple as that.

I post the relevant part of the thread:

> Open Resource.pak, extract the 2 files that are in gameData\magic
> (spells.xml and spell.xsd) into x:\Steam\steamapps\common\majesty
> 2/resource.mod/gameData/magic
>
> Take into special consideration gamedata\magic\spells.xml open up with
> notepad and change the cost of any spell to a negative number and you
> gain gold whenever you cast a spell. e.g. spell name="magic_lightning"
> cost_money="-2500" icon="magic_lightning"
> player_spell_gfx="thunderbolt" target_gfx="thunderbolt_posteffect"
>
> This will grant me 2500 gold for each click.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest 'spell' to use is the rogue's Extortion because it can be used so early and quite cheaply. In the spells.xml file just search for magic_extortion and change the money_cost to -2000 (or however much you want each time you use Extortion.